# Jekyll 2.0 listing all post from category breaks

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I moved from Jekyll pre-1.0 to 2.0 recently.

In my original code, on each blog post it will list all the title of posts that belongs to the same category as the current post being viewed. Previously this code worked:

```
{% for post in site.categories.[page.category] %}
    <li {% if page.title == post.title %} class="active" {% endif %}>
    <a href="{{ post.url}}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

However in the new version this does not work and I have to specify the category individually like so:

```
{% for post in site.categories.['NAME_OF_CATEGORY'] %}
```

Why can't I dynamically check for the category as before? And is there a work around for this instead of using `if` statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I figured it out**. I had, in each post, my YAML front-matter category variables in uppercase or Camel case. Example: `category: ABC` or `category: Zyx`.

Doing `page.category` will always return the the actual category as it was written in the front-matter, which is `ABC` or `Zyx`. However `site.categories.[CAT]` only accepts `CAT` in lower cases (down case in liquid language).

Hence this will work `site.categories.['abc']` or `site.categories.['xyz']`. 
But this will fail `site.categories.['ABC']` or `site.categories.['Xyz']`. It is the same as doing `site.categories.[page.category]`.

**Solution**. Assign the current page category in lower case like so:

```
{% assign cat = page.category | downcase %}

   {% for post in site.categories.[cat] %}
       <li {% if page.title == post.title %} class="active" {% endif %}>
       <a href="{{ post.url}}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
   {% endfor %}
```